# `getElementById` returning null

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

A case of `document.getElementById` returning `null`. I've read four other questions in SO, and read the reference on MDN, but I have no clue of what's wrong; please help me. Code is as follows:

HTML

```
<button id="btnButton1">Button1!</button><br>
<button id="btnButton2">Button2!</button><br>
<span id="spanOutPut"></span>
```

Javascript

```
getBYid = function(elem) {
    return document.getElementById(elem); }

funButton1 = function() { getBYid('spanOutPut').innerHTML = "Button 1 pressed!!" };
funButton2 = function() { getBYid('spanOutPut').innerHTML = "Did you press the Button 2?!" };

getBYid("btnButton1").addEventListener('click', funButton1, false);
getBYid("btnButton2").addEventListener('click', funButton2, false);
```

I get a `TypeError: getBYid(...) is null`, on FireBug.

It works when I simply remove the calls to `addEventListener` from the JS and set `onclick` inline, as in the following code:

```
<button onclick="funButton1()">Button1"</button>
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Is your Javascript before the buttons in the HTML?

Comment: note: I think this is just a typo here, but funButton1's call in your second example is missing brackets.

Comment: @Barmar, no, it wasn't. that was the problem.

Comment: @tomysshadow, ty for that, but that was a wrong copy from the working code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put this after those elements have been loaded into the DOM

Comment: Thank you... I feel so silly now

Comment: @pewpew I added all the listeners inside a `init()` and added `window.addEventListener('load', init)`